# update materialized view with join statement

Tags: clickhouse

Suppose I have 2 tables `A` and `B`. I create a `MV`(materialized view) with a `join` query of two tables, psuedo like:

```
create materialized view a_b engine = Memory as 
select * from(
    select * from A
) all inner join (
    select * from B
) using some_col;
```

I known that `a_b` is [only updated when inserting data](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/queries/#create-view) into table `A` and nothing else happen when push data to `B`. **I want my MV have to update when both table are updated.**

My workaround is to create another `MV` that change postition of `A`, `B` and point to `a_b` like

```
create materialized view a_b_2 to a_b as 
select * from(
    select * from B
) all inner join (
    select * from A
) using same_col;
```

I have some questions about this approach: 
 1. Are there any `more legal way` to archive same effect in `clickhouse`?
 2. Suppose I have 2 incoming batches data `BD_A` and `BD_B` are going to insert to `A` and `B` simultaneously. Some data of 2 batches themself (`BD_A_B`) is fit `join` condition . Is there any chance that the `MV` lost those `BD_A_B` because `MV a_b` processes `BD_A` with before-inserted `B` and `MV a_b_2` processes `BD_B` with before-inserted `A`.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to achieve this. The implementation of materialized view in ch relies on one and only one input block stream which can only be related to one table. It's also inefficient to update the view upon the right join table since it needs to recreate a hash table each time, or else keeping a large hash table and cosuming a lot of memory.

Comment: @nabongs I've got the same problem. But for me, it does not work even only `A` table is updated. My view is always empty. Do you have some solution? The code is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @Amos So the question is why would I use `Materialized View` if I cannot use join? It doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @Joozty For me, as mentioned,  it works when insert to `A` and if I want to it auto update when `B` is updated I must create another `MV` point to first MV.

Comment: What engines do you use for your `A` and `B` table? I asked a similar question on GitHub and I got an [answer](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2612#issuecomment-404213745) that it is not possible. I am wondering it is working for you because it shouldn't have...

Comment: @Joozty `MV` is mainly used for pre-aggregation in Clickhouse.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you are trying to have a workaround of a limitation.

Clickhouse does not support multiple source tables for a MV and they have quite good reasons for this. I actually asked this to devs and got [this answer](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/6213#issuecomment-516842226):

> In ClickHouse materialized view behaves more like BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER, each time processing new block arrived with insert.
>
> So that is quite natural limitation as inserts to 2 different table will come asynchronously and you usually expect to see in JOINs whole table not only newly arrived blocks.